# Run function when specific page is loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a site with an iframe in it, both parent and iframe pages are owned by me on my domain.  I am trying to make it so that when a specific page is navigated to in that iframe (or any page containing a certain string in its URL), a function is called.  I am pretty sure I need to use `location.href` since `src` retains its original value no matter what you do in the iframe. Right now I am just testing by trying to get an alert to show up.  So far I have tried this:

```
if(
 document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow.location.href.indexOf("command") > -1) {
                alert("your iframe url contains the phrase command");
                }
```

Nothing happens when I use this, nothing shows up in the console, etc.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your browser support needed, I might suggest trying to use postMessage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send a message from the iframe that the parent will listen for, to know to run whatever logic it needs.

Comment: Agree. postMessage would be much simpler

Comment: I've never used that before - Would I just include the postMessage command in the `body onload` of the pages loaded in the iframe?

Comment: @HenryFloyd doesn't even need to be in `onload` since it is not dom related. But yes ... in page(s) you want parent window to know about

Comment: How is navigation accomplished? A link? A button? Telepathy? If it's done by a link or button then add an eventListener to said link/button and run the function as the callback function. If it's done by telepathy, you'll probably have to wait until the API is released.

Comment: That was easier than I thought!  I added the EventListener in the `<head>` of the parent page and the postMessage command in the `<head>` of the iframe pages in question.  I will have to use this more often.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question because the actual answer was through comments on the question)

It made much more sense to just use postMessage.  I simply added a postMessage in the `<head>` of the iframe:

```
<script>parent.postMessage("start", "*");</script>
```

...and an EventListener to in the `<head>` of the parent page, to listen for the message:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
        if(e.data == "start") stopwatch.start();
    }, false);
</script>
```